# If $\ln(x)$ is gamma distributed, what is the distribution of $x$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

Additionally, if someone could help calculate the mean and variance of $X$, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**
Let $\ln X = Y \sim \Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$ then
$$
F_X(x)
 = \mathbb{P}[X \le x]
 = \mathbb{P}[\ln X \le \ln x]
 = F_Y(\ln x)
$$
and using the Chain Rule,
$$
f_X(x) = F'_X(x) = f_Y(\ln x)/x
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is there a name for this specific distribution?

Comment: @rmb5769 not that i know of, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Just do derive what gt6989b said:

$$
\frac{f_Y(\ln x)}{x} = \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)x}\ln(x)^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta\ln(x)} = \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\ln(x)^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta} 
$$